# Why isn't array literal size mismatch caught at compile time?

Tags: d

I have the following code:

```
import std.stdio;

int main(string[] args)
{
   int[3] my_array = [1, 2];
   return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine, and then aborts when executed, giving this error:

```
arrays_init
object.Exception@src/rt/arraycat.d(31): lengths don't match for array copy
----------------
arrays_init(_Dmain+0x64) [0x416bbc]
arrays_init(extern (C) int rt.dmain2.main(int, char**).void runMain()+0x1c) [0x418c5c]
arrays_init(extern (C) int rt.dmain2.main(int, char**).void tryExec(scope void delegate())+0x2a) [0x4185d6]
arrays_init(extern (C) int rt.dmain2.main(int, char**).void runAll()+0x3b) [0x418ca3]
arrays_init(extern (C) int rt.dmain2.main(int, char**).void tryExec(scope void delegate())+0x2a) [0x4185d6]
arrays_init(main+0xd1) [0x418561]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7f60bc41d30d]
```

This runs fine if the array literal has 3 items, so apparently the array literal has to match the size of the static array. But shouldn't this give a compile error since the size of both can be calculated at compile time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Array literals are of type `T[]`, i.e. they are dynamic arrays that are unaware of their size at compile time.

Your code compiles for the same reason this compiles:

```
void foo(int[] xs)
{
    int[3] ys = xs;
    ...
}
```

The compiler simply doesn't know how big `xs` is.

In your case, the compiler *could* know at compile time because all the information is there, but it would be going above and beyond what the compiler is obligated to do. Interpreting the code strictly, there is no type mismatch, so it compiles.

Another side effect of array literals being dynamic arrays is that the code you have will actually allocate memory. It allocates the dynamic array on the heap, copies into the static array, and then you have to wait for a garbage collection cycle before the memory is reclaimed. This can be a cause of bad performance if you initialise arrays like that in a tight loop.

Again, the compiler *could* avoid the allocation, but DMD at least does not in the current version (2.060).

Comment: Fortunately, it _is_ the plan to make it so that the OP's code won't allocate anymore (in which case, it'll probably produce an error), but it hasn't been high enough on the TODO list to be done yet.

Comment: Maybe they could use the C array literal syntax for initializing static arrays.

Comment: @Scooter That's not really any reason to. The only reason that assigning an array literal to a static array allocates is because it required creating an optimization for it to not allocate. It was simpler to allocate like is done with all other array literals. Changing it to not allocate in this case costs us nothing (aside from the effort required to make the change), and using another syntax doesn't buy us anything. It would require mostly the same stuff underneath the hood anyway, so why bother creating a new syntax for it? Just properly optimize what we currently have.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis Why is an array literal a dynamic array in the first place?

Comment: @Scooter Probably because that's frequently what you want (more frequently than static in my experience, though that depends on the programmer I suppose), and it's safer for it to default to dynamic than static. If it defaulted to static, then it would be very easy to accidentally slice a static array, which is unsafe and should be done with care (as the slice could outlive the static array). It shouldn't be a big deal to just make the literals static when they're assigned to static arrays, which fixes the problem. It's just that someone has to do it, and other things have been higher priority

Answer (score 7):

That would be because the type of `[1, 2]` (dynamic array) does not preserve the number of elements in the array, so by the time the compiler gets to the assignment (`=`), it doesn't know how many elements are in the expression on the right side.

To put it simply: the compiler simply isn't smart enough.

Comment: What does the .length property of dynamic arrays say - just the capacity??

Comment: @Scooter: The length property is _dynamic_ i.e. a runtime thang. The compiler could be _made_ in theory to deduce all this information at compile-time, the same way your eyes can; but the language doesn't _require_ it and it simply doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of this line:

```
int[3] my_array = [1, 2];
```

on left hand side you are saying 3 values in array i.e you are defining `static array of 3 ints` , but assigning two values only.

Change it to:

```
int[3] my_array = [1, 2, 3];
```

and problem should get solved.

Comment: @CyberShadow: Yes, missed it first time.